# redefine typedef in public headers

Tags: c, typedef

I am trying to define a `typedef` to a structure in private header file and redefine this in the public header as it is used as an argument to a function and as only the private header should be included for use, as in the `main.c` example. I have seen the done in a larger project but cannot seem to get this working in a test project. Creating the type in the main source file results in the error `variable has incomplete type {typeName}`

The basic example is seen below

**fnc_private.h**

```
#ifndef _FNC_PRIVATE_H_
#define _FNC_PRIVATE_H_

typedef struct fncStruct_t
{
    int a;
    int b;
} fncStruct_t;

#endif
```

**fnc.h**

```
#ifndef _FNC_H_
#define _FNC_H_

typedef struct fncStruct_t fncStruct_t;

int myFnc(fncStruct_t *h);

#endif
```

**fnc.c**

```
#include "fnc.h"
#include "fnc_private.h"

int myFnc(fncStruct_t *h)
{
    return h->a + h->b;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "fnc.h"

int main(void)
{
    fncStruct_t h = {3, 4}; // results in 'variable has incomplete type {fncStruct_t}'

    printf("sum = %d\n", myFnc(&h));

    return 0;
}
```

If I'm doing something stupid here, I cannot seem to see what it is. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you expect your `main` module to be able to define an object `h` of type `fncStruct_t` if it does not know the definition of the type? If you only have a declaration of the structure tag, `struct fncStruct_t`, then all you can do is work with pointers to the structure. You cannot create instances of the structure. When you are doing this, you have to provide code in `fnc.c` that creates instances of the structure, such as a routine that takes the initial values for the members, allocates memory, fills in a structure in the allocated memory, and returns a pointer to it.

Comment: I completely agree, I'm not really sure how this would work in its current form. However, this 'seems' to be how this is being done in the large project that I am referencing this method from. Clearly, I must have missed something when looking over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

main.c doesn't see the full definition of `fncStruct_t`, only a declaration, so it can't create a variable of that type.

What you can do is create a pointer to that type, then have a function in fnc.c that dynamically creates the object and returns it to you.

fnc.h

```
#ifndef _FNC_H_
#define _FNC_H_

typedef struct fncStruct_t fncStruct_t;

fncStruct_t *init(int a, int b);
int myFnc(fncStruct_t *h);

#endif
```

fnc.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "fnc.h"
#include "fnc_private.h"

int myFnc(fncStruct_t *h)
{
    return h->a + h->b;
}

fncStruct_t *init(int a, int b)
{
    fncStruct_t *h = malloc(sizeof *h);
    h->a = a;
    h->b = b;
    return h;
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "fnc.h"

int main(void)
{
    fncStruct_t *h = init(3, 4)

    printf("sum = %d\n", myFnc(h));
    free(h);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes this how I would have original solved this, and the project that I am referencing this from does have this form of in `init` API, it seems that I can still reference the structure without needing to init it using preallocated memory. Clear I have missed something when looking at it.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer as it is the only possible implementation I can see.

Comment: One could have not aliased with a `typedef` and it would be even simpler, in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I guess in that larger project the equivalent of fnc.h included fnc_private.h. You can do the same here.

Otherwise the error message is completely normal. In main.c the details of the structure are not visible so it's an incomplete type.

It's possible to define new types, declare functions by just telling the compiler that it's a structure. It's equivalent to showing the declaration of functions. But when you want to create a variable from your structure type, or reference its members, the complete definition of the structure must be visible to the compiler.